# Cannot convert value of type NSURL? to expected argument of type _?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm working on getting more comfortable with generics and I have run into this problem multiple times.  I get a compiler error where it tells me it can't convert 'type' to expected argument type '_'.  I'm having trouble understanding this error.  I thought that specifying a generic param allows you to pass in any type?  Or is that not what I'm doing?

```
infix operator +++ { associativity left }

func +++<A, B>(a:A?, f:A -> B?) {
    if let x = a {
        f(x)
    }
}

func stringToImage(string:String, completion:(Result<UIImage>) -> ()) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        if let image:UIImage =  urlFormat(string) +++ dataFormat +++ imageFormat { --- Cannot convert value of type NSURL? to expected argument of type _?

        } 

    })
}

func urlFormat(s:String) -> NSURL? {
    if let url = NSURL(string: s) {
        return url
    }
    return nil
}

func dataFormat(url:NSURL?) -> NSData? {
if let u = url {
    if let d = NSData(contentsOfURL: u) {
        return d
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func imageFormat(d:NSData?) -> UIImage? {
    if let data = d {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            return image
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `+++` func doesn't return anything.

Since there is nothing return from `urlFormat(string) +++ dataFormat`, calling `+++ imageFormat` doesn't work since there is nothing on the left side.

You just need to change `+++` so it has a return value like this.

```
func +++<A, B>(a:A?, f:A -> B?) -> B? {
    if let x = a {
        return f(x)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: mm I feel dumb. Thank you.